# Typer python : Getting an Error "Error: Got unexpected extra argument (stringvalue)" when passing a string to my function

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, typer

So i was trying to make a to-do list CLI application in python using Typer and I want it to display a message when no task is provided to it . So i set task with a default value of None
But when I pass a value to task eg "driving" I get an error "Got an unexpected extra argument"
Any suggestions on how to fix this error or maybe another solution to display an error when no argument is passed to the function
Heres my code:

```
@app.command()
def add(priority:int, task="None"):
    if task=="None":
        print("Error: Missing tasks string. Nothing added!")
    else:
        dict1={}
        dict1.update({task:priority})
        filesize1= os.stat('output.pickle').st_size
        if filesize1==0:
            pf=open("output.pickle","wb")
        else:
            pf=open("output.pickle","ab")
        pickle.dump(dict1, pf)
        pf.close()
        pf=open("output.pickle","rb")
        dict2={}
        while 1:
            try:
                dict2.update(pickle.load(pf))
            except EOFError:
                break
        pf.close()
        dict3={k:v for k,v in sorted(dict2.items(),key= lambda v:v[1])}
        print('Added task: "'+task+'" with priority '+str(priority))
    
        file1=open("ls.txt","w+")
    
        i=1
        for  key,value  in dict3.items():
            file1.write(str(i)+". "+key+ " ["+str(value)+"]"+"\n")
            i=i+1
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I've encountered the same problem with the typer version of 0.7.0

Let say we have a file called `addition.py` and there is your function `add` decorated as typer command. Then, first what I did is I've checked what `--help` flag would give me and I got the following:

In your terminal run:

```
python addition.py --help
```

[image]

Here you see that `task` argument is optional and has to be passed differently.

If you run:

```
python addition.py 123456 --task "SOMETHING"
```

Then this works perfectly when you have **only one function** in your `addition.py` file

If you have other functions with the `@app.command()` decorator then you have to indicate function name in terminal

```
python addition.py add 123456 --task "SOMETHING"
```